# how to use cgroups in php exec

Tags: php, linux, ffmpeg, cgroups

I'm trying to use cgroups in php

And I did the following :

```
sudo cgcreate -g cpu:/www-data
sudo cgset -r cpu.cfs_period_us=1000000 www-data
sudo cgset -r cpu.cfs_quota_us=100000 www-data
```

And when I do use it on ffmpeg via the terminal it works fine

But when I used it in php like :

```
exec("cgexec -g cpu:www-data ffmpeg -i music.mp3 -ac 1 -map 0:a -acodec libopus -b:a 64k -vbr off -ar 24000 music.ogg");
```

does not work

Can it be used with exec?

Answer (score 0):

Check the output

```
exec("cgexec -g cpu:www-data ffmpeg -i music.mp3 -ac 1 -map 0:a -acodec libopus -b:a 64k -vbr off -ar 24000 music.ogg 2>&1", $output, $return_var);
var_dump($output);
```